# Change linear-gradient with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am working on a project involving input type color. I need to make a gradient using these, how would I do this?

Here is color tags

```
<div id="part1" align=center>
<input type="color" id = color>
<input type="color" id = color2>
```

EDIT:
ive only tried tried

```
$("body").css("background-color",clr);
```

but that cant do gradients as far as I am aware

Comment: Show what you've tried!

Comment: you mean to set the color that choosed as background of body

Comment: what? I mean I want to change background: linear-gradient(red,blue) so that I can use input type="color" to change the color of the gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code provided is not completed:

1. What does the variable clr mean?
2. When will the input value take effects on the background?

Here I would provide a sample code that I try to guess what you want to do as

> I mean I want to change background: linear-gradient(red,blue) so that I can use input type="color" to change the color of the gradient

Here is the sample code to use a button to assign the background with gradient color.
Hope this can help you.

```js
$("#btn_color").on('click', function(){
 var color = $("#color").val();
  var color2 = $("#color2").val();
  var str = "linear-gradient(" + color + "," + color2 + ")";
  $("body").css("background",str);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="part1" align=center>
  <input type="color" id ='color'>
  <input type="color" id ='color2'>
</div>
<button id="btn_color">Click me </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the value of the gradient desired in the `background` property

Check this url for more information https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Here I put a working example:

```js
function changeBackground(){
  const color1 = document.getElementById("color").value;
  const color2 = document.getElementById("color2").value;
  document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(${color1}, ${color2})`;
}
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="part1" align="center">
  <input type="color" id ="color">
  <input type="color" id ="color2">
  <button onClick="changeBackground()">Change background!</button>
</div>
```